# Is there a way to reduce redundancy when declaring variables like this?

Tags: python

```
max_vert = list(itertools.accumulate(map(len, vertices)))
min_vert = [0] + max_vert[:-1]

num_indices = list(itertools.accumulate(map(len, indices)))
first_index = [0] + num_indices[:-1]
```

I have this code, and I'm wondering if there's a way to reduce redundancy and make it more compact. Is there a way? What's the most compact way of doing this? All variables being declared are very similar as shown above. If there is a more compact way of doing the same as above, is it better? What would it look like?

Comment: Use (create) a helper function?

Comment: Do you mind posting what it would look like, if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1):

Create and reuse a helper function:

```
def max_min(stuff):
    max_stuff = list(itertools.accumulate(map(len, stuff)))
    min_stuff = [0] + max_stuff [:-1]
    return max_stuff , min_stuff 

max_vert, min_vert = max_min(vertices)
num_indices, first_index = max_min(indices)
# and reuse again if you have more similar definitions / computations ...
```