# Refactoring this Selenium Script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need help refactoring this code using a function to reutilize WEbDriverWait and Search for IDs and Classes without repeating the same statements over and over. The script works as intended but I wanted to know a more "pythonic way" to code it. I've tried several ways but with no avail. "By." doesn't let me use a variable after itself to call for the Search Option nor concatenate a Str...I cant figure out how to do it.

```
def click_button(TypeSearch, nameElement):
    newSearch = str(TypeSearch).upper()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.newSearch, nameElement)))
    driver.find_element(By.newSearch, nameElement).click()

click_button('ID', 'user-email')
click_button('ID', 'user-password')
```

Code Base:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Credentials
username = "<SOME_USERNAME>"
password = "<SOME_PASS>"

# Initializing Chrome's webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH/TO/DRIVER, options = options)

# Loading atlassian's login page
driver.get("SOME_URL")

# Login Attempt ||  Username (Email Address)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'user-email')))
element.send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"login-button").click()

# Login Attempt ||  Password
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'user-password')))
element.send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"login-button").click()

# Click On Customer Service Desk Button
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'elrEjn')))
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'elrEjn').click()

# Click On Technical Support Option
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'joNJss')))
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'joNJss').click()

# Fill up Summary & Description Fields
dataSummary = "Summary Automation TEST RSM Tool"
dataDescription = "Descriptor Automation TEST RSM Tool"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'summary')))
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'summary').send_keys(dataSummary)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ProseMirror')))
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ProseMirror').send_keys(dataDescription)

# Locating the Submit Button
# Click() Function On Line 64 Commented For Testing Purposes
# NOTE 1: When Uploading into a Production Environment: Uncomment the Submit Click() Function 
# NOTE 2: When Uploading into a Production Environment: Comment Line Above Submit Click() Function & Print Function @ The Bottom

xpath_submit = '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/form/div/div/div[6]/button[1]'
#submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_submit)
submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_submit).click()
#print(submit.text)
```

Comment: Define and reuse a helper function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to reduce redundancy when declaring variables like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72342344/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-redundancy-when-declaring-variables-like-this)